# Generar un pdf con domPdf en laravel

Tags: laravel

Buenas tardes tengo un pequeño problema y es el siguiente
tengo mi ruta para el pdf la cual es la siguente:

```
Route::resource('cuadre','CuadreController');
    Route::get('vista-html-pdf',array(
            'as'=>'vistaHTMLPDF',
            'uses'=>'CuadreController@vistaHTMLPDF'
        ));
```

y este el de mi controlador:

```
public function vistaHTMLPDF(Request $request) {
  $fecha1;
  $fecha2;
  $zona;

  //trayendo objeto de cuadre con todos los atributos guardados en store  
  $guia =Cuadre::orderBy('idcuadre','ASC')->paginate(5);
  foreach($guia as $guias) {
    $id = $guias->idcuadre;
    $zona = $guias->idzona;
    $fecha1 = $guias->fechainicial;
    $fecha2 = $guias->fechafinal;      
  }

  /*consulta para borrar los registros a la hora de darle al boton cerrar */
  //  $fechacierre =DB::delete('delete  from asignacion where idzona='.$zona.
  //                      ' and ts between '.$fecha1.' and '.$fecha2);



  /*Consulta de zona pereira*/
  $cua = DB::select('select forma_pago ,sum(valor_neto) as s 
                     FROM asignacion as a, 
                     guia_manual as b where b.idguia_manual = a.idguia and
                     idzona='.$zona.' GROUP by forma_pago');

  //consulta para traerme el resumen de los pagos y el total de guias creadas en pereira
  $resumen =  DB::select('select remision,forma_pago,valor_neto
                                         FROM guia_manual g,
                                         asignacion a WHERE a.idguia = g.idguia_manual and idzona='.$zona);

  /*Consulta de zona bogota*/
  $bog2 = DB::select('select forma_pago,sum(valor_neto) as s
                                         FROM asignacion as a,
                                         guia_manual as b
                                         where b.idguia_manual = a.idguia and
                                         idzona='.$zona.'  
                                         GROUP by forma_pago');

   if($request->has('descargar')){
     $pdf = PDF::loadView('vista-html-pdf');
     return $pdf->download('reporte');
   }

   if($zona=='12'){
     return view('vista-html-pdf')->with('cua',$cua)->with('resumen', $resumen)->with('zona',$zona);
   } elseif ($zona=='13') {
     return view('vista-html-pdf')->with('bog2',$bog2)->with('resumen', $resumen)->with('zona',$zona);
   }
```

y esta mi vista para el pdf:

```
<div class="botones">
  <div class="form-group">
    <a href="{{route('vistaHTMLPDF',['descargar'=>'pdf'])}}" class="btn btn-warning">Ver Pdf </a>
  </div>
</div>
<?php if ($zona =="12"): ?>
  <table style="width: 18%" class="table table-striped">   

    @foreach($cua as $cuas)
      <tr>
        <th>total {{$cuas->forma_pago}}: </th>
          <td>{{$cuas->s}}</td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
    </table>
      <table style="width: 30%" class="table table-striped">
        <th>Guias</th>
          <th>Forma pago</th>
            <th>Valor</th>
              @foreach($resumen as $remisiones)
              <tr>
                  <td>{{$remisiones->remision}}</td>
                  <td>{{$remisiones->forma_pago}}</td>
                  <td>{{$remisiones->valor_neto}}</td>
              </tr>
              @endforeach        
            </table>
          <tbody>
        </tbody>   
    <?php endif ?>

    <?php if ($zona=='13'): ?>
      <table style="width: 18%" class="table table-striped">  
        @foreach($bog2 as $bogs2)
          <tr>
            <th>total {{$bogs2->forma_pago}}: </th>
            <td>{{$bogs2->s}}</td>
          </tr>
           @endforeach
          </table>

          <table style="width: 30%" class="table table-striped">
              <th>Guias</th>
              <th>Forma pago</th>
              <th>Valor</th>
              @foreach($resumen as $remisiones)
              <tr>
                  <td>{{$remisiones->remision}}</td>
                  <td>{{$remisiones->forma_pago}}</td>
                  <td>{{$remisiones->valor_neto}}</td>
              </tr>
              @endforeach        
          </table>
          <tbody>
          </tbody>
  <?php endif ?>
```

y esta mi vista final:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero al presionar el boton ver pdf me sale que las variables que estoy mandado a la vista no estan definidas pero no se porque.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

```
 $pdf = PDF::loadView('vista-html-pdf');
```

Aquí no le pasas variables como en la vista normal

```
 return view('vista-html-pdf')->with('cua',$cua)->with('resumen', $resumen)->with('zona',$zona);
```

Comment: Ya lo resolvi muchas gracias, y si era eso no le estaba pasando las variables ademas de que toca crear una vista nueva solo para el pdf y sin table porque genera error.

Comment: El problema es que por defecto no puedes usar ni php ni javascript en las vistas,ademas de que las rutas de los ficheros apuntan a storage en lugar de public